# PHP Function Returns Match or No Match

Tags: php, boolean, match

I am new to PHP and am trying to write a simple function that takes two variables and returns the string "match" if the variables are the same and returns "no_match" if they are different. Again new to programming, so thanks in advance!!

Comment: I'd tend to suggest you look at the [basic PHP syntax for functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) and other chapters in the manual. It's fine to ask questions on SO, but knowing the basics will massively accelerate the learning process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a function to do this:

```
$result = ($var1 === $var2) ? "match" : "no_match";
```

But if you insist:

```
function matches($var1, $var2, $strict = false) {
   return ($strict ? $var1 === $var2 : $var1 == $var2) ? "match" : "no_match"
}
```

Usage:

```
$v1 = 1;
$v2 = "1";

var_dump(matches($v1, $v2)); //match
var_dump(matches($v1, $v2, true)); //no_match

$v1 = "1";

var_dump(matches($v1, $v2, true)); //match
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Compare two values for equality/equivalence
 * @param mixed
 * @param mixed
 * @param bool compare equivalence (types) instead of just equality
 * @return string indicating a match
 */
function compare($one, $two, $strict = false) {
   if ($strict) {
      $compare = $one === $two;
   }
   else {
      $compare = $one == $two;
   }
   if ($compare) {
      return 'match';
   }
   else {
      return 'no_match';
   }
}
```

Comment: Way too readable. Try `return (($strict) ? $one === $two : $one == $two) ? "match" : "no match";` Much more what I'm used to seeing in PHP. ;-)

Comment: Way too readable?  Isn't readability a good thing?  Nesting ternary operators is confusing and dangerous .. I also chose to leave it out for a new person so as not to confuse them.